# Unable to access forwarded ports

Tags: windows-7, router, port-forwarding

I have attempted the same process on two routers with the same result. Whatever I try the ports I expose refuse external connections. I have included some screenshots, hopefully they help:

My internal IP (I have tried using DHCP and manually assigning the IP in windows (while reserving on the router) - no difference) I'm including this so you can see that in the next screen I am forwarding to the correct IP:

[image]

The port forwarding set up on my router (firewall OFF on both router and windows, and I have checked that my ISP firweall is also off), as you can see pointing at the correct internal IP:

[image]

The result of a remote port check (on any of the ports listed above):

[image]

This is all part of trying to get Overwatch to work correctly, as it regularly loses connection to the server. Using blizzards 'Looking Glass' for Overwatch (EU) I receive **100%** packet loss. http://us-looking-glass.battle.net/

What else can I try? Why are these ports still inaccessible? What could be blocking them?

Comment: Make sure you are using your router's external IP and not your internal IP (obviously) and make sure your ISP allows inbound connections on that port -- this is harder to do.  You may be able to access logs on your router or stop routing entirely (basically putting your PC directly on the Internet) -- I wouldn't do the latter for long!  If you have a remote VPS, trace route the connection to your machine and see where it gets dropped.  Connection refused usually means a hard and fast deny rather than something simply not responding.

Comment: @GraemeWicksted yes the port checker is using the external IP (it detects it automatically). I have done some research and apparently my ISP (Plusnet) doesn't block any inbound ports, and the ISP firewall (which WOULD) is off. What logs would I be looking for on my router? It seems to collect some but this isn't in my comfort zone. No remote VPS. EDIT: It doesn't appear that my router logs are collecting anything relevant here, just system and DHCP stuff.

Comment: Try using an online tcptraceroute provider to see where things drop off.  Possibly: https://www.websitepulse.com/help/testtools.tcptraceroute-test.html